# How do I color parts of a string BEFORE drawing the string to the screen with curses?

Tags: python, colors, curses

Is there any way that I can color a word in a string **before** I even `addstr` it to the curses screen?  I have tried to do this at a low-level by concatenating things like `"\033[31m"` (and then `"\033[0m"` at the end) to the string, but curses does not recognize that and just spits out something like: `this is a ^[[31mlink^[[0m`.  If you do not understand so far, this may help:

```
# pseudocode
a = "this is a link"
replace "link" in a with colorRed("link")
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use `addstr` or are you amenable to using some different APIs?

Answer (score 0):

No: programs that use curses do not send escape sequences.  Instead, they pass strings and attributes.  The curses library puts those together and sends escape sequences.

In the C interface for curses, that could be done per-character by OR'ing the attribute onto `chtype` values (or packing `cchar_t` using [`setcchar`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getcchar.3x.html)).  Alternatively, one could set an attribute on the window and write a string using that attribute with [`addstr`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_addstr.3x.html).

Python provides (according to its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html)) a *different* interface to `addstr`.  The section *[Attributes and Color](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html#attributes-and-color)* shows this example:

```
stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "Current mode: Typing mode", curses.A_REVERSE)
```

to add a reverse-video string, and this:

```
stdscr.addstr("Pretty text", curses.color_pair(1))
```

to add a string using color pair #1.  Color pairs combine foreground (text) and background colors.

Python's interface to changing the window attributes more closely resembles the C interface: it provides [`attrset`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_attr.3x.html), `attron`, [`bkgd`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_bkgd.3x.html) methods as shown in its documentation for [Window Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#window-objects).

As a general guideline, you would not get good results by writing your own escape sequences directly (bypassing the curses library):

- curses uses its own output buffering, which may not be connected to your standard output buffer (so things may be written in an unexpected order)
- if you wrote something that changed the screen's appearance, curses would not know about that, and the result would not be helpful.

Comment: I know how to color text using the curses drawing interface, I just don't know how to (or if its possible) set the text color BEFOREHAND.